# Sort an array in Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is an array `emails` having few attributes `To, From, Subject, Description`. I retrieve records from database and populate all rows in this array. I use to access all rows as follows:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < emails.length; i++) {
    var To = emails[i].To;
    var Sender = emails[i].Sender;
    var Subject = emails[i].Subject;
    var Description = emails[i].Description;
 }
```

Now I need to sort this array alphabetically by `To` values and store the sorted emails in another array `sortedemails`. How can I do this in easiest possible way in Javascript/JQuery?

Thanks.

Comment: alphabetically by To ?

Comment: first link is the answer to your question

Answer (score 2):

Arrays in javascript have a sort function.

```
emails.sort(function(a, b) { 
   if (a.To < b.To) {
     return -1;
   } else {
      return 1;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript arrays have a built-in `.sort` method.  No loops (or jQuery needed).

```
emails.sort(function(a, b){
    return a.To.localeCompare(b.To);
});
```

This will modify the `email` array.  If you want to save the original (unsorted) array, you'll need to copy the array before sorting.

```
var sortedemails = emails.slice(0);
sortedemails.sort(function(a, b){
    return a.To.localeCompare(b.To);
});
```